# How to modify my existing query to take into account a particular column from a custom made table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I'm using SQL Server 2014  and and extract of my current query stands as shown below. My question relates to the last SELECT statement of my query. Right now it works fine and the output is as follows:

```
ReservationStayID ........... XBEV01   XBEV02   XBEV03  XFOOD1   XFOOD2
     215          ...........  1500      0        0      300       100
     356          ...........   500      200      0      600       700
     620          ...........   300      0        600     0        200
```

Now I have created a table called "Extras" and it looks like this:

```
 Code       Description          RevenueType
XBEV01     Beverage Bar A      Beverage Charge
XBEV01     Beverage Bar A      Beverage Charge
XBEV01     Beverage Bar A      Beverage Charge
XFOOD1     Food A              Food Charge
XFOOD2     Food B              Food Charge
```

I want to modify my query so that the output looks like this:

```
ReservationStayID ........... Beverage Charge     Food Charge
     215          ...........  1500                  400
     356          ...........   700                 1300
     620          ...........   900                  200
```

I know that I need to do a LEFT JOIN with the "Code" column of the "Extras" table with the "FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE" column of the "P5FolioCharge" table but I can't figure out how to implement it in my query.
I guess I will need to modify the SUM statements in the last SELECT statement of my query.

Here is an extract of my current query:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT 
  x.[ReservationStayID],
  b.PropertyCode,
  c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
  j.FOH_PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER,
  y.FOC_ACCOUNT,
   .......  
  b.GuestCount AS 'Total Guest',
  x.[Nights Spent] AS 'Room Nights',
  x.[MTH],
  x.[Rate] AS 'Room Rate WITH VAT',
  c.CurrencyCode, --added
  h.ROE AS 'Rate of Exchange', 
  (x.[Nights Spent]*x.[Rate]*h.[ROE])/NULLIF(1.15,0) AS 'PkgRevenue, Excl. VAT', 
  ((x.[Nights Spent]*x.[Rate]*h.[ROE])/1.15)/NULLIF((b.GuestCount*x.[Nights Spent]),0) AS 'GADR, Excl. VAT', 
  x.CreatedOn,
  x.[DateOfArrival],
  x.[DateOfDeparture],

  e.TravelAgencyTypeCode AS 'Source of Business', 
  c.TAProfileID, 
  e.Name AS 'Tour Operator',
  g.CountryGroup AS 'Market',
  c.TAProfileID2, --added
  e2.Name AS 'Booking Origin (1)', 
  g2.CountryGroup AS 'Booking Origin (2)',
  y.[NetAmount(XBEV01)],
  y.[NetAmount(XBEV02)],
  y.[NetAmount(XBEV03)],
  y.[NetAmount(XFOOD1)],
  y.[NetAmount(XFOOD2)]

  FROM GuestNameInfo a
  JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
  LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
  LEFT JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID 
  LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID 
  LEFT JOIN Market g ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode --added
  LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e2 ON e2.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID2
  LEFT JOIN Market g2 ON e2.CountryCode = g2.CountryCode --added
  LEFT JOIN Exrate h ON h.Ccode = c.CurrencyCode -- added
  LEFT JOIN RoomCat i ON b.PropertyCode = i.Property AND d.rsl_roomtype = i.RoomType 
  LEFT JOIN P5FOLIOHEADER j ON J.FOH_PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER =    C.PMSConfirmationNumber


 LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT 
     ReservationStayID,
     datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) as [MTH],
     count(*) AS [Nights Spent],
     avg(RateAmount) as [Rate],
     min(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn,
     min(StayDate) as [DateOfArrival],
     max(StayDate) as [DateOfDeparture]
    FROM ReservationStayDate
   GROUP BY ReservationStayID, datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' +  cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar)
 ) x ON x.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID



  LEFT JOIN
 (
 SELECT 
         FOC_ACCOUNT,
         datename(m,FOC_DATE) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,FOC_DATE) as varchar) as [FOCMTH], 

        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XBEV01' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XBEV01)',
        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XBEV02' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XBEV02)',
        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XBEV03' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XBEV03)'
        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XFOOD1' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XFOOD1)',
        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XFOOD2' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XFOOD2)'

 FROM P5FOLIOCHARGE

 GROUP BY FOC_ACCOUNT, datename(m,FOC_DATE) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,FOC_DATE) as varchar)

) y ON y.FOC_ACCOUNT = j.FOH_ACCOUNT
```

---

UPDATE:
Here is my Pivot Query (based on the proposed solution by Merely Useful) and it works. I created a VIEW Table (HOLDINGS3) and made a pivot query to tap into the VIEW:

```
    (SELECT ReservationStayID,
            PropertyCode,
            [Beverage Charge],
            [Food Charge]

    FROM (SELECT 
          ReservationStayID,
          PropertyCode,
          RevenueType,
          FOC_NETAMOUNT

      FROM HOLDINGS3

    )ab

      PIVOT (SUM(foc_netamount)

      FOR RevenueType IN ([Beverage Charge], [Food Charge]
         )) as pvt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go. Your query is very long so this might not work but hopefully it will give you an idea. This section is hindering you:

```
SELECT 
         FOC_ACCOUNT,
         datename(m,FOC_DATE) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,FOC_DATE) as varchar) as [FOCMTH], 

        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XBEV01' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XBEV01)',
        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XBEV02' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XBEV02)',
        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XBEV03' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XBEV03)'
        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XFOOD1' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XFOOD1)',
        SUM(case FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE when 'XFOOD2' then foc_netamount else 0 end) as 'NetAmount(XFOOD2)'
```

You are better off just left joining on the table, left joining on your new extras table and then pivoting out the columns you need.

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT <<ALL THE DESCRIPTIVE COLUMNS YOU NEED>>,
[Beverage Charge],
[Food Charge]
FROM
(
SELECT 
  x.[ReservationStayID],
  b.PropertyCode,
  c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
  j.FOH_PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER,
  y.FOC_ACCOUNT,
   .......  
  b.GuestCount AS 'Total Guest',
  x.[Nights Spent] AS 'Room Nights',
  x.[MTH],
  x.[Rate] AS 'Room Rate WITH VAT',
  c.CurrencyCode, --added
  h.ROE AS 'Rate of Exchange', 
  (x.[Nights Spent]*x.[Rate]*h.[ROE])/NULLIF(1.15,0) AS 'PkgRevenue, Excl. VAT', 
  ((x.[Nights Spent]*x.[Rate]*h.[ROE])/1.15)/NULLIF((b.GuestCount*x.[Nights Spent]),0) AS 'GADR, Excl. VAT', 
  x.CreatedOn,
  x.[DateOfArrival],
  x.[DateOfDeparture],

  e.TravelAgencyTypeCode AS 'Source of Business', 
  c.TAProfileID, 
  e.Name AS 'Tour Operator',
  g.CountryGroup AS 'Market',
  c.TAProfileID2, --added
  e2.Name AS 'Booking Origin (1)', 
  g2.CountryGroup AS 'Booking Origin (2)',
  RevenueType,
  foc_netamount


  FROM GuestNameInfo a
  JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
  LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
  LEFT JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID 
  LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID 
  LEFT JOIN Market g ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode --added
  LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e2 ON e2.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID2
  LEFT JOIN Market g2 ON e2.CountryCode = g2.CountryCode --added
  LEFT JOIN Exrate h ON h.Ccode = c.CurrencyCode -- added
  LEFT JOIN RoomCat i ON b.PropertyCode = i.Property AND d.rsl_roomtype = i.RoomType 
  LEFT JOIN P5FOLIOHEADER j ON J.FOH_PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER =    C.PMSConfirmationNumber


 LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT 
     ReservationStayID,
     datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) as [MTH],
     count(*) AS [Nights Spent],
     avg(RateAmount) as [Rate],
     min(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn,
     min(StayDate) as [DateOfArrival],
     max(StayDate) as [DateOfDeparture]
    FROM ReservationStayDate
   GROUP BY ReservationStayID, datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' +  cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar)
 ) x ON x.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID

LEFT JOIN PSFOLIOCHARGE
    ON PSFOLIOCHARGE.FOC_ACCOUNT = j.FOH_ACCOUNT

LEFT JOIN Extras 
    on Extras.Code = PSFOLIOCHARGE.FOC_TRANSACTION_CODE
)vals
PIVOT ( SUM( foc_netamount) FOR (RevenueType IN([Beverage Charge],[Food Charge]) AS pvt
```

I would be completely amazed if this ran without modification on your DB as I have no way of testing it short of recreating your tables but it should give you an idea of how to proceed.